# Integer vector comparison with permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, vectors, normed-spaces

I'm considering a discrete problem with integer vectors, and I don't know whether there exists some literature about such problems. Perhaps somebody recognizes the structure of this problem.

So, suppose I am considering some integer $n$ and correspondingly the vector $v = [1,\ldots,n]^T$. If I now take any permutation matrix $P$, I also consider the permuted vector $Pv$. Now I am considering the difference:
$$v - Pv$$
In particular, I am interested in either the $1$-norm or $2$-norm of this vector, so:
$$||v-Pv||_1 \quad \text{or} \quad ||v-Pv||_2.$$
What I want to know is the average of either (any of both would be fine) of this quantities of this difference vector over all possible permutations $P$, as an expression in $n$.

If possible, I would even like to know something about the distribution of this quantity, i.e. the likelihood of of finding some value for $||v-Pv||_1$ in case for the $1$-norm. But that would be an additional question.

Comment: The [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) seems to be powerful here.  Try expressing the result of the 1-norm as a combination of random variables.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't think it would work. Since the combination you speak of would consist of dependent variables, and then you can not apply this result

Comment: Linearity of expectation works for dependent variables as well.

Comment: Ah yes, you are absolutely right, that makes the expectation problem rather easy actually. Thanks a lot!